# What type of Canadian Visa for conference and tourism?

Tags: visas, canada

What type of Canadian visa should I apply for to attend a conference and tourism in Canada? Is it a work visa or a visit visa?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The type of visa you need is the same regardless of whether you go for business, tourism or transit. Canada calls this the *temporary resident visa*. You may choose business while applying for the visa, and you will receive a temporary resident visa which is good for all of these purposes.

Comment: Do I select this option for conference: "I want to conduct international business activities in Canada, but will not enter the Canadian labour market."

Answer (score -3):

Your primary visit is the conference, so get a work visa, you can then use this to conduct tourist activities.

Comment: A work visa is not appropriate for a temporary business or tourist visitor.